# Alfresco : How to search for a specific files types?

Tags: lucene, alfresco

I am working to search all PNG files(i.e. all files which has file name extension ".png") in alfresco.
I am using the followingcode, but it does not return any result:

```
var docs = search.luceneSearch("@cm\\:content.fileType:\"*.png\""); 
for (var i=0; i<docs.length; i++)
   {
     //TO print the name of files--> "Name: " + docs[i].name ;

   }
```

I am not sure if **content.fileType** is the right way to code to search for file types. Any suggestion please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use this statement, it helps to find only PNG images:

```
var docs = search.luceneSearch("@cm\\:name:\"png\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should go with the `content.mimetype` query, for example: `@\{http\://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0\}content.mimetype:text/plain`

https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-4673-search#jive_content_id_Finding_nodes_by_content_mimetype

Comment: Lista, it returns all different files types  (.png, .txt,. gif, .pdf and all whichever is in the system).  How to make it specific to return only ".png" files ?

Answer (score 0):

If your really want to search for PNG files you should follow Lista's approach using mimetype but with correct syntax

```
var docs = search.luceneSearch("@cm\\:content.mimetype:\"image/png\"");
```

searching for name part "PNG" ("@cm\:name:\"png\"") would find any document having a token "PNG" in it's name like png.name.pdf or any_png.doc since document name is stored tokenized in the index

Comment: Context of my question is: I see many files in my alfresco system are of type "somenames.png" but their mimeTypes: image/jpeg. Those images are creating a problem to display in IE. Therefore I finding all the .PNG files and treat them separately. Hence my approached worked, though I have to manually failter non-png files, as you have stated, but it helped me to solve my problem. I appreciate you solution. Thank you !